# Boost::mpi sending array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

Good Morning
I'm implementing a distributed image normalization algorithm an I'm using Boost::mpi with a class Pixel that contain the serialization code,

```
#ifndef PIXEL_H
#define PIXEL_H

#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>

class Pixel
{
    private:
        unsigned char m_red;
        unsigned char m_green;
        unsigned char m_blue;
        friend class boost::serialization::access;

        template <class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
            ar & m_red;
            ar & m_green;
            ar & m_blue;
        }
    public:
        Pixel();
        Pixel(unsigned char red,unsigned char green,unsigned char blue) : m_red(red), m_green(green), m_blue(blue) {};
        virtual ~Pixel();
        unsigned char getRed();
        void setRed(unsigned char val);
        unsigned char getGreen();
        void setGreen(unsigned char val);
        unsigned char getBlue();
        void setBlue(unsigned char val);
        void setColor (unsigned char red,unsigned char green,unsigned char blue);
};
```

The main.cpp is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "include/Pixel.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#define ALTEZZA 2
#define LARGHEZZA 2

namespace mpi=boost::mpi;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::cout<<"Inizializzazione dell'ambiente MPI"<<std::endl;
    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;
    Pixel **vettore;
    int i,j;

    //Inizializzazione della matrice di test
    if(world.rank() == 0){
        std::cout<<"Inizializzazione matrice di test..."<<std::endl;
        std::srand(std::time(0));
        vettore = new Pixel *[ALTEZZA];
        for (i = 0; i < ALTEZZA; i++) {
            vettore[i] = new Pixel[LARGHEZZA];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < ALTEZZA; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < LARGHEZZA; j++) {
                vettore[i][j].setColor(std::rand() % 256, std::rand() % 256, std::rand() % 256);
                std::cout<<"Vettore["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] = ("<<int(vettore[i][j].getRed())<<","<<int(vettore[i][j].getGreen())<<","<<int(vettore[i][j].getBlue())<<");"<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    if (world.rank() == 0) {
        std::cout<<"Invio matrice.."<<std::endl;
        world.send(1, 0, vettore[0]);
    }else {
        Pixel *px;
        world.recv(0, 0, px);
            for (j = 0; j < LARGHEZZA; j++) {
                std::cout<<int(px[j].getRed())<<" "<<int(px[j].getGreen())<<" "<<int(px[j].getBlue())<<std::endl;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but when i run the program the cout on the receiving process print wrong value like this

```
Inizializzazione dell'ambiente MPI
Inizializzazione dell'ambiente MPI
Inizializzazione matrice di test...
Vettore[0][0] = (170,103,165);
Vettore[0][1] = (84,0,186);
Vettore[1][0] = (93,228,162);
Vettore[1][1] = (31,100,204);
Invio matrice..
170 103 165
217 1 0
```

I think that the problem is the 2d array because if I use std::vector i haven't this problem but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine you have several problems (I can't test as I don't have a capable MPI installation..)

Firstly, your `send()` is wrong, currently you are triggering the overload:

```
template<typename T> void send(int, int, const T &) const;
```

But you are trying to send a raw array, I imagine the fix here has to be to pass the count, for example:

```
world.send(1, 0, vettore[0], 2);  // 2 Pixels
```

Secondly, on the receiver side (this I'm not sure about), but I imagine you need to have a suitable array to read the data into.., for example:

```
Pixel px[LARGHEZZA];
world.recv(0, 0, px, 2);
```

I think this should fix your problems...